# Excel 2013 scatter plot

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

Hi I'm creating a sieve analysis graph. The graph is in logarithmic scale but I want the labels in the horizontal axis to be exactly as per the sieve sizes (horizontal data values)

Can I make the horizontal axis labels reflect the sieve sizes? 
Can I make the horizontal major gridlines match the plots?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an XY Scatter chart for your main data series.

Add a helper data series with all Y values set to the minimum value of the log scale and the X values at the desired sieve sizes. Then use data labels (X Value) for that series and place them underneath the data points. Hide the X axis labels and format the helper series data markers to be invisible. Or you can use the + sign as the data marker, so it looks like a tick mark.

For major gridlines you can use error bars on the helper series. Set them to a custom value that is the same as the Max value of the Y axis.

In the screenshot I have applied this technique and used red for the error bar color and the data marker symbol. The only thing left to do is to remove the out of the box grid lines and use gray for the error bars and data marker.

[image]